# method setFitsSystemWindows(true) does nothing

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

My project contains one MainActivity and 6 Fragments. I would like to have the layout set to fit system window for 1 certain fragment and not others. So what I did is I put this code 
`getActivity().findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout).setFitsSystemWindows(true);` 
inside the onResume method in that one fragment and 
`getActivity().findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout).setFitsSystemWindows(false);` inside the onResume method in others.

> Turn out that the method `setFitsSystemWindows(false)` works but the
>   `setFitsSystemWindows(true)` does nothing

The application view still set to not fit System Windows after calling `setFitsSystemWindows(true)`  so I would like to know if I've done anything wrong or the method just can't work.

Thank you in advance. Any answer will be appreciated.

> UPDATE: I call .getFitsSystemWindows() after calling .getFitsSystemWindows() and it return true -- without doing the task.

Comment: The question like this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28387289/fitsystemwindows-programmatically-for-status-bar-transparency/40717490#40717490

Answer (score -1):

If you want to display something under the status bar, try this

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28041425/3410790) is a more detailed solution.