# How to force windowSoftInputMode adjustResize when statusBar is hidden

Tags: android, android-activity, window-soft-input-mode

I have been struggling to put this to work. The app resizes well as long as i keep the status bar visible. According to this [post](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13000) it is an android bug, but the issue is closed but not resolved.

From all that i read, playing with Insets should do the trick but i can't put it to work. Not sure even if should go this way.

Following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43299028/2700303) i added the below code to OnCreate.

```
ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView(), new OnApplyWindowInsetsListener() {
    @Override
    public WindowInsetsCompat onApplyWindowInsets(View view, WindowInsetsCompat insets) {

        ((ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams()).topMargin =
            insets.getSystemWindowInsetTop();

        return insets.consumeSystemWindowInsets();
   }   
});
```

It throws the exception:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.WindowManager$LayoutParams
>   cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams

The post goes on but i am stuck here and have doubts if i am going the right way.

Bellow the testing code i am using if someone wants to try.
Works well until the statusbar is removed by adding    `<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>` to AppTheme.

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"> 
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

activity_mail.xml:

```
<!-- this control should be position static -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:text="static window at top"
        android:gravity="center"
        />

<!-- the resizable view  -->
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/my_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:transcriptMode="normal">
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

<!-- use this EditText box to call softKeyboard-->
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
    android:id="@+id/cv_bottom_bar_edit"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.AutoCompleteTextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:gravity="center"
    />
```

row.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#F06060"
    android:layout_margin="30dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:gravity="center"
>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.my_list);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    String[] myDataset = new String[]{"1", "2", "3","4","5","6","7","8","9"};

    mAdapter = new MyAdapter(myDataset);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

}
```

**Update:**
   I moved the windowFullscreen attribute from manifest to AppTheme because Android was not reading it from the manifest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class AndroidBug5497Workaround extends AppCompatActivity {

// For more information, see https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36911528
// To use this class, simply invoke assistActivity() on an Activity that already has its content view set.

private ViewGroup contentContainer;
private ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver;
private Rect contentAreaOfWindowBounds = new Rect();
private LinearLayout.LayoutParams rootViewLayout; //-->change to the view root control type of your view.
private int usableHeightPrevious = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    contentContainer = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    rootViewLayout = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) contentContainer.getLayoutParams();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (viewTreeObserver.isAlive()) {

        viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(listener);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (viewTreeObserver == null || !viewTreeObserver.isAlive()) {
        viewTreeObserver = contentContainer.getViewTreeObserver();
    }

    viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(listener);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    contentContainer = null;
    viewTreeObserver = null;
}

ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener listener = new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        contentContainer.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(contentAreaOfWindowBounds);
        int usableHeightNow = contentAreaOfWindowBounds.height();

        if (usableHeightNow != usableHeightPrevious) {
            rootViewLayout.height = usableHeightNow;
            contentContainer.layout(contentAreaOfWindowBounds.left, contentAreaOfWindowBounds.top, contentAreaOfWindowBounds.right, contentAreaOfWindowBounds.bottom);
            contentContainer.requestLayout();

            usableHeightPrevious = usableHeightNow;
        }
    }
};
```

}

Got it from [facebook/react-native](http://android:windowSoftInputMode=%22adjustResize%22%20will%20not%20work%20when%20StatusBar%20hidden=%22true%22%20Android%20#13000) issue on github. Slight simplified for a common activity. Works good with portrait and landscape, from api 21, but it not much more tested than that. Use with care.

Answer (score 0):

Notice this line:

```
((ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams()).topMargin =
            insets.getSystemWindowInsetTop();//what's the parent of "view"
```

According to [getLayoutParams](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#getLayoutParams()) says, you should know what's the parent of "view" ,for example, if the parent is `FrameLayout`, then do like this:

```
((FrameLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams()).topMargin =
                insets.getSystemWindowInsetTop();
```

If the parent is relativelayout or linearlayout, also switch to definite type like above.

**Edited:** try this:

```
((WindowManager.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams()).topMargin =
                    insets.getSystemWindowInsetTop();
```

Comment: I had try both. Casting to activity top control LinearLayout.MarginLayoutParams still throws the error. WindowManager has no property MarginLayoutParams. 
I may handling the even on the wrong view.